# How do I uninstall codeblock?

Tags: code-blocks

I installed codeblocks 12.11 on Ubuntu 12.10 manually from terminal using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and then uninstalled it from software center. The icon is still shown in the main lens but doesn't work any longer.

How can I remove the app completely from system??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since you installed using dpkg, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo dpkg --remove <package name>; sudo dpkg --purge <package name>
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get purge <package name>
```

If you still have problems then look at [How to Completely Remove a Package](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-completely-uninstallremove-a-packagesoftwareprogram)

Comment: May also try `sodu apt-get remove codeblocks`

Answer (score 0):

You can use synaptic package manager. Type codeblocks in the search bar and mark the shown painted in green files for complete remove and that's all. In my case that helped me removing code::blocks.